# Ruby :id is coming null from params[:id]

Tags: ruby, routes, parameters

I'm writing a form and I seem to be missing my params[:id] when it gets to the Content Controller.

This is my routes.rb:

```
match '/site/content/myaction/:id', :to => 'contents#myaction'
```

The form is "myaction" which is in a partial _edit.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'myaction' do %>
    <input id="old_id" name="myaction_name" type="text" />
    <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

before I submit the form i'm at: `/site/content/edit/:id/`
after i hit submit and i'm at the error page i'm at:  `/site/content/myaction/`

It gets to myaction in content controller but i get the error that id is null... and here are the params:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "old_id"=>"2",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "id"=>nil}
```

What I am missing? it seems that maybe it's not picking my route? how else is it re-directing then...

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: have you defined myaction as 'POST' in routes?

Comment: I just tried it... i commented out the match in my rules and replaced it with: post "site/content/myaction/:id", :to => 'contents#myaction'. Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the id to the url for the form:

```
form_tag :action => 'myaction', :id => 5 do
```